# In cshell, how can I echo a form-feed character?

Tags: echo, csh, tcsh

I find myself unable to do a simple progress bar in a cshell script, without being able to output a form-feed. Is this totally unsupported by cshell? (or tcshell)?

Are there any alternatives to output a progress bar (and an ending point of progress), to run shell-commands between iterations of progress?

Could I use awk instead? Awk is pretty obscure to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `printf` command (which is not specific to csh or tcsh).  To print a formfeed character (ctl-L):

```
printf '\xc'
```

To demonstrate:

```
% printf '\xc' | od -c
0000000  \f
0000001
```

But are you sure formfeed is the character you want? It typically has no effect in a VT-100 compatible terminal emulator.

You can print arbitrary control character sequences, as defined by termcap, with tcsh's built-in `echotc` command. `man tcsh` and search for `echotc` for details; `man 5 termcap` to see the 2-character codes recognized by `echotc`.

More portably (to shells other than csh and tcsh), the `tput` command, part of the `ncurses` package, is similar to `echotc`, but it uses terminfo capability names rather than termcap (though it also supports termcap if support is compiled into the package).